# Sonarqube scm author doesn't auto assign and display garbled when scm account was Chinese

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube5.6

SonarQube Version: 5.6 LTS

Plugin: sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3

When Author is Chinese, it can't be auto-assigned, and the Chinese characters are shown as "_" in the source viewer.
How to fix this problem?

[image: click here to view image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, I reproduced the issue. I created a [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8250). Feel free to vote.